# Does elasticsearch 7.3 rest client discover new nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch, deployment, load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

I have an elasticsearch 7.3 cluster with 3 nodes. 
My application is using es rest client in order to communicate with es. Client uses connection url which is **node1:node2:node3**

My question - is it possible to add new **node4** to es cluster so that rest client discover it (of course without app restart)? Or maybe rest call will be to node1 which will somehow redirect it to newly added node.

ps. I started to think about above mentioned question - whether I need LB between client and es cluster or no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in es doc.

> Once a RestClient instance has been created, a Sniffer can be
>   associated to it.  The Sniffer will make use of the provided
>   RestClient to periodically (every 5 minutes by default) fetch the list
>   of current nodes from the cluster and update them by calling
>   RestClient#setNodes.

Link to doc - [rest client usage, sniffer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.3/_usage.html)